# Inheritance and subclasses basics

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass

I'm new to creating subclasses and do not know how I can "restrain" the functionality of the subclass although I'm using the superclasses' functionality.

In my subclass, I want to use the `getCash()` method in my superclass, but I only want it to give me a result, if there has been more than 5 days since the `date` stored in my subclass. My code looks like this:

```
public class Super{

    private double cash;

    public Super(double cash){
        this.cash = cash;
    }

    public void deposit(double amount) {
        if (amount > 0){
            this.cash += amount;
        }
    }

    public double getCash(){
        if (this.cash > 0){
            return this.cash;
        }else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

public class Sub extends Super {

    private LocalDate date;

    public Sub(double cash) {
        super(cash);
    }
}
```

Is this the right way of attacking the problem? Or should I implement all the logic needed in my superclass, and just pass a variable telling it wether it's the superclass or the subclass calling the function? What is the best practice?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you said makes sense: you should indeed overwrite in subclasses, and call super when needed; but your snippet does not do that, nor it compiles, as the getCash methods have paths that do not return a double value (i.e., else). Could you comment more about it?

Comment: @LuanNico I was a little fast when writing the example code in Atom, but the compilation problem has been fixed now. As for the overwriting; do you know if the functions has to be copied exactly the way they are in the superclass, with variable names and everything?

Answer (score 1):

You can use polymorphism to redefine functions in a subclass.
The function needs to have the same same signature (name + parameters).

```
public class Sub extends Super {

private LocalDate date;

  public Sub(double cash) {
    super(cash);
   }

  public double getCash() {
  if (/* your date check */) {
     return super.getCash();  
    }
   return 0.0;
  }
}
```

Thanks to [shikjohari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30198368/3042945).
See : [JAVA Polymorphism](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm)

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware this was common practice, as it seems a little weird for a subclass to "overwrite" its superclass.

Comment: `this.cash` will not work as its not visible in the subclass if I m not wrong

Comment: You have to see it like that : the subclass is a specialization of the superclass.  Specialization means creating new subclasses from an existing class in which you can override the superclass' methods.

Comment: I didnt mean that you have to change it to protected. Its a bad practice to make a variable protected just because you want to use it in the subclass. :)

Comment: Oh fine, my bad. I saw you answer and it's clearly a better way to do it :).  @joseph If your question is solved please mark it :).

Comment: Joseph, accept one of the aswers if was helpful. Please :)

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of returning only when the date difference is of 5 days is your subclass's behaviour so you have to write that condition in subclass only, However after the condition check you can call the `super.getCash()`

I think you can use the method in your subclass as

```
public double getCash() {
    if (/* your date check 8*/) {
        return super.getCash();  
    }
    return 0.0;
}
```